# Anchors in tour page

Tags: feature-request, new-users, help-center

In multiple cases with new comers, I have difficulties to mention how to use that small `edit` button (link).

So, is possible to have some anchors in tour page. To easy use like pointing user to the exact interesting portion. Some thing like:

https://askubuntu.com/tour#edit

Or is the objective of that, the new user should read the whole page anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the tour page is really designed for those who are very new to the Stack Exchange network. It's a 2 minute overview of our USPs but doesn't really go into much detail... So yeah, I think it's expected that if people want to know what we're about as a site, they'll view the tour first.

It's in the [real help page for editing](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing) where you find out when you should and shouldn't be editing. If you want to push existing users somewhere, *that's* the page you want them to read.

Comment: Now it seems to me reasonable, after I see/monitor the other review queues for some time. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This could be really easily fixed by making the `class` attributes on the tour page sections `id` attributes instead.

But, yes, the tour page is only intended as a full read for new users, so they can get a short intro - the complete /help knowledge base contains a lot more detailed, and more easily linkable, information.

Comment: Now I admit that in most cases, I need to push (and even harder) new users to read those help topic. Thank you that was helpful.